# Wrong color legends with two plots overlay in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, r-sf

I'm trying to give a combined color scheme in spatial plot using ggplot2 this way:

- A Factor (2 levels) variable is used to select the tint (in my case, orange or blue)
- A continuous variable is used to select the saturation

I found no easier way to do that than stacking two plots, the upper one a grey gradient to simulate saturation:

```
    ggplot(data = italian.regions) +
  geom_sf(fill = c("#BFD6FF", "#FFEBBF")[as.numeric(as.factor(regions.lookup$`engine.top`))], lwd = .2) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = regions.lookup$`engine.diff`), lwd = .2, alpha = .3) +
  scale_fill_gradient(high = "#666666", low = "#EFEFEF")
```

I use the aestethic to fill the gradient and this works. This is an example plot:

[image: example plot]

But (of course) the color legend refers to the aesthetic but it should be much more meaningful to have one describing the discrete values in 'engine.top'.

Is it possible to do so? is there an easier way to have a two-tonal, gradient color scheme without stacking two plots?

Comment: Multiple related scales like this have been [discussed a lot](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/578), with some workarounds ([here's a bunch](https://www.google.com/search?q=ggplot+multiple+color+scales+site:stackoverflow.com)). Two recent packages, multiscales and ggnewscale, try to implement something like this. Also, it's easier to help more specifically, or see how this has already been addressed, if you include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: tnx allot, I'll try to make a reproducible example, although it sounds really tricky due to the very wide dependencies my maps have

Comment: You could just pull together a few simplified shapes and the indicators you're coloring them by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My prefered method is to use `scale_fill_identity()` and `hcl()`. See if this works for you

```r
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

# this file is already on your computer 
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))


nc_colors <-
  nc %>% 
  mutate(
    # 220 = blue and # 40 = orange
    hue = ifelse(str_detect(CNTY_ID, "^18"), 220, 40),
    light = AREA/max(AREA)*100,
    # the hcl function returns a hex code
    hex = hcl(h = hue, l = light)
  )


ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc_colors, aes(fill = hex)) +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]

Another solution you can use is to do something like `aes(...fill = hue, alpha = AREA)` then use `scale_fill_manual()`

Comment: Just want to throw out that this is a beautiful solution. I so rarely see good color manipulation like this, and think to do it myself even more rarely

Comment: This works like a charm, very elegant and efficient! Thanks a lot!